# The zeros of finite product of Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\{a_i\}_{ i=\overline{1,n}}$ are complex number with $|a_i|<1$. Let $$f(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{z-a_i}{1-\bar{a_i}z}.$$
Now we need to prove that $f'(z)\neq 0$ on $|z|=1$ and that $f'(z)$ has precisely $n-1$ zeros in $\{z\vert |z|<1\}$.

what I was confused is not sure how to use argument principle here to prove nonzero on the boundary and I'm trying to avoid direct calculations.

Any kind of thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f^{'}}{f}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-|a_k|^2}{(z-a_k)(1-\bar{a}_k z)}$$

Set $z=e^{i\theta}$:

$$\frac{f^{'}}{f}(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-|a_k|^2}{(e^{i\theta}-a_k)(1-\bar{a}_k e^{i\theta})}=e^{-i\theta}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-|a_k|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-a_k|}$$

So $f^{'}$ is nonzero on the unit circle. Then we can use the argument principle for $f^{'}$. Define:

$$f_t(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{z-ta_k}{1-t\bar{a}_k z}$$

When$0\leq t\leq 1$, $f_t$ enjoy all the properties of $f$. Moreover it is easy to see that:

$$N(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f_t^{''}}{{f_t}^{'}} dz$$

By what proved above, $N(t)$ is well define and continuous. But its range must be integer set. So $N(t)$ is constant. $N(1)=N(0)=n-1$.

Thanks Hang Yuan for valuable suggestion.